# Programatically add and remove tkinter python labels causes IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, ttk

Sorry for the vague title but I didn't know how to explain myself better. Basically what I try to do in tkinter here is adding and removing labels. The label value gets updated so that I always have an increment of 1 even though I deleted a label in the beginning. If I generate labels and delete them from the bottom up I have no problems but it I delete one from the middle and then try to clean my list I get an error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/XXXX/Helper/development/dynamicListLabels.py", line 21, in <lambda>
    labelList[index].append(ttk.Button(root, text="Remove", command=lambda: removeLabel(labelList[index][0], index)))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

My python code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from Tkinter import *
import ttk


def removeLabel(labelToRemove, bla):
    labelList[labelToRemove.get()][1].destroy()
    labelList[labelToRemove.get()][2].destroy()
    del labelList[labelToRemove.get()]
    for label in labelList:
        index = labelList.index(label)
        label[0].set(index)


def addNewLabel():
    labelList.append([IntVar()])
    index = len(labelList) - 1
    labelList[index][0].set(index)
    labelList[index].append(ttk.Label(root, textvariable=labelList[index][0]))
    labelList[index].append(ttk.Button(root, text="Remove", command=lambda: removeLabel(labelList[index][0], index)))
    labelList[index][1].grid(column=0)
    labelList[index][2].grid(column=1, row=labelList[index][1].grid_info()['row'])


root = Tk()
labelList = []
ttk.Button(root, text="add label", command=addNewLabel).grid(column=1, row=0)
root.mainloop()
```

And my GUI looks like this:

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Design

1. The main problem comes when dealing with different indexes. Trying to manipulate them carefully leads to complicated operations resulting in a long and inefficient code. To remedy to this problem, we simply get rid of them and take advantage of the label class variable `Tkinter.IntVar()` you already are using. This gives us full control of the labels and associated widgets.
2. An other efficient decision to take that prevents from getting lot of headache is to attach each (label, button) couple widgets to a unique `Tkinter.Frame()` instance. This offers the advantage of deleting the frame using [`destroy()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.destroy-method) method leading automatically to the destruction of the widgets it contains. In the same time, this keeps the look of your GUI and makes your it [scalable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability) as it offers you the possibility to add more widgets.

**Designing `addNewLabel()`**

There is nothing new here compared to your original code except, as I said in 2. each (label, button) couple will be drawn into a single and unique `Tkinter.Frame()` instance. Of course, the list frames must be declared global in this method.

**Designing `removeLabel()`**

From 1. the only argument we need to pass to `removeLabel()` is the Tkinter variable (`var` in the code below) inherent to the label we want to get rid of.

We need then to loop over list of frames (`frames` in the code below) using [`winfo_children()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_children-method) to seek for the label which has the text variable we are looking for.

Note that [because](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/winfo.htm#M21) I draw the label before the button inside individual frames, `winfo_children()` returns as first widget list element the label

> **winfo_children()**:
>
> Returns a list containing the path names of all the children of window. Top-level windows are returned as children of their logical
>   parents. The list is in stacking order, with the lowest window first,
>   except for Top-level windows which are not returned in stacking order.
>   Use the wm stackorder command to query the stacking order of Top-level
>   windows.

This is why it is correct to write : `if frame.winfo_children()[0].var == var` and destroy the frame that contains the label which satisfies this condition.

## Solution

Here is the program. I commented the lines which I think deserve to be commented:

```
'''
Created on Jun 25, 2016

@author: billal begueradj
'''

from Tkinter import *
import ttk


def removeLabel(var):
    global frames
    z = -1
    # Loop over the list of rames
    for frame in frames:
        z = z + 1
        # Check the text variable of the label of this frame
        if frame.winfo_children()[0].var == var:
           # Destroy the related frame
           frame.destroy()
           # Update the size of the list of frames
           frames = frames[:z] + frames[z+1:]
           # Do not forget to always rest this flag back to -1
           z = -1 

    # Update the labels' numbers       
    r = 0
    for frame in frames:
        frame.winfo_children()[0].var.set(r)
        r = r + 1


def addNewLabel():
    global  frames, i
    var = IntVar()
    frame = Frame(root)
    i = i + 1
    frame.grid(row=i, column=0)    
    var.set(len(frames))
    l = ttk.Label(frame, textvariable=var)
    l.grid(row=0, column=0)
    l.var = var
    b = ttk.Button(frame, text="Remove", command=lambda: removeLabel(var))    
    b.grid(row=0, column=1)
    frames.append(frame)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   root = Tk()
   frames = []
   i = 1
   ttk.Button(root, text="add label", command=addNewLabel).grid(column=0, row=0)
   root.mainloop()
```

## Demo

Let us create 6 labels:

[image]

Now let us delete the label number 3. You can see that the numbering of the labels is automatically updated:

[image]

Now let us add a new label. You can see the newly added label has a number which is consecutive to the last existing label number in the list:

[image]

Note that the length of the list is updated all the time as you wanted.

Comment: Just a heads up, now it doesn't update label numbers and if you do add-remove-add-remove couple times, you'll get multiple same numbered labels.

Comment: Yes this does not reduce the list size and update the IntVar() of the labels.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I relied this time only on the content of the Tkinter variables to avoid the mess @Lafexlos

Comment: WOW thanks for this amazing explanation. I am still trying to understand everything completely but hey I am learning here. Thanks a lot for your time Billal BEGUERADJ and also @Lafexlos!

Comment: BTW I didn't know that you can just add a variable/property to a widget in the way you did it (l.var = var). This is really handy!